Relation about $\text{Spin}^c$ and Spin groups
Let $V$ be a real vector space of finite dimension equipped with a an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and call $Q(v)=\langle v,v\rangle$ the positive definite quadratic form associated with it. We can extend $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ to a non-degenerated $\mathbb{C}$-bilinear form $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\mathbb{C}$ on its complexification $V_\mathbb{C}=V\bigotimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}$ by defining $\langle v\otimes z,u\otimes w \rangle_\mathbb{C}=\langle v, u\rangle zw$. Letting $Q_\mathbb{C}$ be the quadratic form associated with $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\mathbb{C}$ it is possible to show that $\text{Cl}^c(V,Q)=\text{Cl}(V,Q)\bigotimes_\mathbb{R}\mathbb{C}$ is naturally isomorphic to $\text{Cl}(V_\mathbb{C},Q_\mathbb{C})$ as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.
There are "two" important definitions of "spin groups" on $\text{Cl}^c$ under this identification. The first one would be the spin group of $\text{Cl}(V_\mathbb{C},Q_\mathbb{C})$, that is, $\text{Spin}(V_\mathbb{C},Q_\mathbb{C})=\text{Pin}(V_\mathbb{C},Q_\mathbb{C})\cap\text{Cl}_0(V_\mathbb{C},Q_\mathbb{C})$, where $\text{Pin}(V_\mathbb{C},Q_\mathbb{C})$ is the multiplicative group generated by all $\sigma\in V_\mathbb{C}\setminus 0$ such that $Q_\mathbb{C}(\sigma)\in\{-1,+1\}$ and $\text{Cl}_0(V_\mathbb{C},Q_\mathbb{C})$ is the subspace of even elements of the Clifford algebra, and the other would be the "complexified" spin group, $\text{Spin}^c(V,Q)=\{e^{i\theta}\nu|\nu\in\text{Spin}(V,Q)\}$ (from now on I will use $z\nu=\nu\otimes z$ for elements in $\text{Cl}^c(V,Q)$).
At first I thought that $\text{Spin}(V_\mathbb{C},Q_\mathbb{C})=\text{Spin}^c(V,Q)$, but if $\text{dim}_\mathbb{R} V\geq 2$ then $e_1,ze_1+we_2\in\text{Pin}(V_\mathbb{C})$, where $z=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i$, $w=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i$ and $\{e_j\}$ is an orthonomal basis for $V$ (since $Q_\mathbb{C}(e_1)=Q_\mathbb{C}(ze_1+we_2)=1$), and of course $e_1(ze_1+we_2)=-z+we_1e_2\in\text{Spin}(V_\mathbb{C})$, but if you try to write $-z+we_1e_2=e^{i\theta}\nu$, for $\nu\in\text{Spin}(V)$, letting $\nu=\sum_I r_I e_I$, where $r_I\in\mathbb{R}$, we would find that $\text{arg}(-1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i)=\text{arg}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i)$, what is false. Then I thought that maybe $\text{Spin}^c(V)\subset\text{Spin}(V_\mathbb{C})$, but then $e^{i\theta}\in\text{Spin}^c(V)$ for any $\theta$. However, if $e^{i\theta}\in\text{Pin}(V_\mathbb{C})$, then we could write $e^{i\theta}=\sigma_1...\sigma_n$, $\sigma_k\in V_\mathbb{C}\setminus 0$, $Q_\mathbb{C}(\sigma_k)\in\{-1,1\}$, and, following the proposition 2.5 on Lawson and Michelsohn "Spin Geometry", we arrive that $e^{2i\theta}=N(e^{i\theta})=N(\sigma_1)...N(\sigma_n)=\in\{-1,1\}$, what restricts $\theta$.
My questions are the following: first, if my rationale is correct, and second, if it is, is there any relation between $\text{Spin}^c(V)$ and $\text{Spin}(V_\mathbb{C})$?

Where have you seen this definition of $\mathrm{Spin}^c(V,Q)$? I don't really see any utility in it. If you had written that without defining it I would have though you meant $\mathrm{Spin}(V_{\mathbb C}, Q_{\mathbb C})$.

@NicholasTodoroff It's used on Seiberg-Witten theory to define Spin structures on manifolds. It was first defined in Atiyah-Bott-Shapiro "Clifford Modules" paper (there it is written as $\text{Spin}(V)\times_{\mathbb{Z}_2}\mathbb{S}^1$, maybe you have seen with this definition)

I just had a look at Atiyah-Bott-Shapiro. That is not how they define $\mathrm{Spin}^c$. They show that their $\mathrm{Spin}^c$ is isomorphic to that. There is some subtlety in their definition as well. In particular, they define the Lipschitz-Clifford group as $$\Gamma^c = {x\in\mathrm{Cl}^c ;:; \forall v\in V.:\alpha(x)vx^{-1}\in V}$$ where $\alpha$ is the main involution. Notice the use of $V$ and not $V^c$. Then $\mathrm{Pin}^c$ is the kernel of $x \mapsto x\alpha(\tau(x^))$ where $\tau$ is the main antiautomorphism and $$ is complex conjugation.

They also define $\mathrm{Pin}(V,Q)$ similarly, which makes it a subgroup of your $\mathrm{Pin}$.
